# handling Voxel block IDs

Tags: c++, struct

I am making a simple voxel engine and have come a fair portion giving the knowledge I have so please, bear with me. I am trying to store information of blocks (IE. Solid, Color, Depth, ect.)

I believe the most effective way to store this information is in stucts? easy access (I think), fast, low memory. anywho, here is what I am doing in code.

```
struct block {
  bool Solid;
  bool BlockR;
  int id;
} AIR, STONE, DIRT, GRASS;
```

now I am trying to find a way to call upon a struct based on information. For example:

If a block is created (say it's AIR) then I could use say mm block.Solid, and it would know that I am referring to AIR.Solid... I don't know if any of that makes sense, that is half of my problem cause I don't know what to search.. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem in voxel engines is the amount of memory tht it needs. So your struct approach is not good. Note that you would have lots of voxels with the same data, that is, a large waste of memory.

One better aproach is to use a hashtable. The voxel stores a key, and the table stores the actual set of different voxel properties used. When you change the properties of a voxel (Change its color from blue to green, for example), you use your hash function with the new properties as input, and looks at the hashtable to find the generated key. If the key is used, assign it to the voxel. If not, store the new voxel properties combination in the hashtable, and assign the new kay to the voxel.

One problem with this is voxel elimination: When we erase a voxel from the game, we always have to delete its voxel properties from the hashtable? The answer is no. Note that more than one voxel could be using that properties.
To solve this, you could implement a simple reference counting system.

Your ID problem is easy to solve: Voxel engines are commonly based in octrees, and as in other trees, you could generate a simple naming convention:

```
(0)-->(10)-->(100)  
  |      |-->(101)  
  |
  |-->(11)-->(110)
         |-->(111)
```

**NOTE:** This convention has a name, but I not remember it. If anyone knows, please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple voxel engine, you really don't even need any structs, they can be replaced by `unsigned char`s specifying the block's id.  Then create arrays with other data like textures (all 6 sides if you like), and what sound it makes when you step on it or break it.  Don't create an array regarding solidity; the id alone can tell you that much.

If you insist on using structs, put on the prefix `__declspec(align(4))` so CPUs don't fall over and die when they see a bunch of misaligned - AKA not 4-byte aligned - data.  It takes up a bit more memory, but it ultimately executes much faster.